# No Interpretations Available When Solving an inhomogeneous Second Linear ODE System(a Forced Vibration Problem)

Tags: differential-equations, physics

My input is:
`DSolve[{m*n1''[t] + k*n1[t] - k*n2[t] == f*E^(I*w*t),  m*n2''[t] - k*n1[t] + 2*k*n2[t] - k*n3[t] == 0,  m*n3''[t] - k*n2[t] + k*n3[t] == 0}, {n1[t], n2[t], n3[t]}, t]`
What's wrong with me? Thanks.

Comment: `E^[I*w*t]` should read: `E^(I*w*t)`

Comment: I changed into E^(I*w*t) but still failed.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {m*n1''[t] + k*n1[t] - k*n2[t] == f*E^(I*w*t), 
   m*n2''[t] - k*n1[t] + 2*k*n2[t] - k*n3[t] == 0, 
   m*n3''[t] - k*n2[t] + k*n3[t] == 0};

(sol = DSolve[eqns, {n1, n2, n3}, t]) // Short[#, 5] &
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {{True, True, True}} *)
```

Simplifying the solutions,

```
solt = {n1[t], n2[t], n3[t]} /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {{1/18 (6 (-((3 E^(I t w) f (k^2 - 3 k m w^2 + m^2 w^4))/(
         m w^2 (3 k^2 - 4 k m w^2 + m^2 w^4))) + C[1] + C[3] + C[5] + 
        t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6])) + 9 (C[1] - C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
     3 (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + (
     Sqrt[m] (9 (C[2] - C[6]) Sin[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
        Sqrt[3] (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sin[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]]))/
     Sqrt[k]), 
  1/9 (-3 (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + (-9 f k^(3/2) Cos[t w] + 
        m w^2 (-3 k + 
           m w^2) (-3 Sqrt[k] (C[1] + C[3] + C[5] + t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6])) + 
           Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
            m] (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sin[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]]) - 
        9 I f k^(3/2) Sin[t w])/(Sqrt[k] m w^2 (3 k - m w^2))), 
  1/18 (6 (-((3 E^(I t w) f k^2)/(3 k^2 m w^2 - 4 k m^2 w^4 + m^3 w^6)) + C[
        1] + C[3] + C[5] + t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6])) + 
     9 (-C[1] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
     3 (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + (
     Sqrt[m] (9 (-C[2] + C[6]) Sin[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
        Sqrt[3] (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sin[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]]))/
     Sqrt[k])}} *)
```

Making use of [`Sinc`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html)

```
solt2 = solt /. Sin[x_] :> x*Sinc[x] // Simplify

(* {{1/6 (-((6 E^(I t w) f (k^2 - 3 k m w^2 + m^2 w^4))/(
      m w^2 (3 k^2 - 4 k m w^2 + m^2 w^4))) + 2 C[1] + 2 C[3] + 
     2 C[5] + 2 t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6]) + 
     3 (C[1] - C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + 3 t (C[2] - C[6]) Sinc[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
     t (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sinc[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]]), 
  1/9 (-3 (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + (-9 f k^(3/2) Cos[t w] + 
        m w^2 (-3 k + 
           m w^2) (-3 Sqrt[
            k] (C[1] + C[3] + C[5] + t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6])) + 
           3 Sqrt[k]
             t (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sinc[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
             m]]) - 9 I f k^(3/2) t w Sinc[t w])/(Sqrt[k]
         m w^2 (3 k - m w^2))), 
  1/6 (-((6 E^(I t w) f k^2)/(3 k^2 m w^2 - 4 k m^2 w^4 + m^3 w^6)) + 
     2 C[1] + 2 C[3] + 2 C[5] + 2 t (C[2] + C[4] + C[6]) + 
     3 (-C[1] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + (C[1] - 2 C[3] + C[5]) Cos[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[
       m]] + 3 t (-C[2] + C[6]) Sinc[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
     t (C[2] - 2 C[4] + C[6]) Sinc[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]])}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!